# Sycn input with readline nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, synchronous

How to sync input with readline function in nodejs? I wanted to take input and store in a variable for later use.

```
const readline = require('readline');

function createReadObject() {
    read = readline.createInterface( {
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    } );
}

var x;
var read;

createReadObject();
read.question("input :",(input) => { 
    x = input;
    read.close();
} );

console.log(x);
```

**output:**
*input :undefined*

It seems readline doesn't wait for the input, rather starts executing later code.

How can make it synchronous with later code? Looking for solution regarding nodejs version 9.4 or **previous**

Comment: have you tried using an async await function?

Comment: "How can make it synchronous with later code?" — You can't.

Comment: "nodejs version 9.4 or previous" — **Danger** [Those versions of Node.js are **beyond** end-of-life](https://github.com/nodejs/Release).